# How to push modified files to git from PHP

Tags: php, github, git-commit

In a backoffice, I'm generating some files that need to replace other files on different websites. Those websites are deployed via Github.

So basically I need to push some files to a Github repo, from PHP.

What's the best way to do that?
Can I only clone those files and not pollute my backoffice with the whole repo?

Comment: It might help of you told us more about your use case. I often hear requests like this regarding configuration files (different per-machine settings, sensitive passwords, ...) or generated files (user uploaded avatars, ...). There are different recommendations depending on what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I really don't think there are. I'm just generating config.inc.php files that I need to push to one github repo, in different folders. That could be images or stylesheets and that wouldn't change anything.

Comment: Except that moving files (that for whatever reason aren't part of your repository) around, using Git as the transport, from PHP, is a pretty unusual thing to want to do. I'm betting that your *actual problem* has a better solution. I wonder if this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/248627). As your question stands I cannot offer you a good solution.

Comment: You're absolutely right. But that's the client's problematic and changing everything would waste them more money than keeping their actual system which is to generate them automatically (still) but deploy them on the repos manually.

They've got a repo for the back-end, a repo for the front-end and another repo. The files generated from the backoffice are languages files than contain keys with translations to different languages used on the front-end. They don't use a DB for that.

Comment: Re-reading your question, it sounds like these files *are* tracked using Git. Is this correct? If so, what's stopping you from using whatever deployment strategy you are using for the rest of the application?